# PHP date_diff parameters are wrong

Tags: php, validation, datetime

I am trying to use date_diff to work out if a date is larger than another, for this I have 2 sets of date (due to the fact I am making a betting system they are bet set and bet till date and time).

I have this validation function:

```
 public function CanBet($bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate, $amount) {
    $can_bet = true;
    $bettilltime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $bettilltime));
    $bettilldate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $bettilldate));

    $betsettime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $betsettime));
    $betsetdate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $betsetdate));
    if ($this->GetUserBalance() > $amount) {
        if (date_diff($betsetdate, $bettilldate) > 0) {
            if (date_diff($betsettime, $bettilltime) > 0) {
                $can_bet = true;
            }
            else {
                $can_bet = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $can_bet = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $can_bet = false;
    }

    return $can_bet;
}
```

And I seem to get the same error every time, it says that date_diff can't take a string when I have reset the params to be a DateTime, like the function asks for - however, this still does not work, what am I doing wrong or what do I need to read?

I have looked at the PHP manual and this (although it did help me to understand) didn't answer my question.

Comment: [as per this PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) you can compare PHP DateTime object like `if($bettilldate > $betsetdate  ){}` it will give Boolean result

Comment: I suspect the 'time' format should be 'H:i:s' rather than 'Y-m-d'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_diff($betsetdate, $bettilldate)` will return `object` and you cant compare it like that. Try to compare the difference of `second`s with -

```
$diff = date_diff($betsetdate, $bettilldate);
if ($diff->s > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and check if it works:

```
$dDiff = $betsettime->diff($bettilltime);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's the date convertions problem. try this :

```
public function CanBet($bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate, $amount) {
    $can_bet = true;
    $bettilltime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y-m-d",$bettilltime)));
    $bettilldate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y-m-d",$bettilldate)));

    $betsettime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y-m-d",$betsettime)));
    $betsetdate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y-m-d",$betsetdate)));
    if ($this->GetUserBalance() > $amount) {
        if (date_diff($betsetdate, $bettilldate) > 0) {
            if (date_diff($betsettime, $bettilltime) > 0) {
                $can_bet = true;
            }
            else {
                $can_bet = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $can_bet = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        $can_bet = false;
    }

    return $can_bet;
}
```